# Login with POST Form, which trigger a javascript validation, and AJAX to a PHP file. Trouble storing data to PHP

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, ajax

**Brief**

I am now stuck at a part of AJAX, as I do now know how to extract the data out from the AJAX part and put into the PHP variables, so that I could access it and use it later. It also does not redirect me to another page ("`Map.php`").

I tried looking online for the answers, but to no avail. Can anyone with experience please help. Also, I am not sure if my method of doing is correct, please let me know where I have done wrong.

**In details**

I want to do a "**Login.php**", which will use a form to take the email and password from the user. There will be a "Login" button on the form which will trigger a javascript for the purpose of validation.

Upon validation, I will use **AJAX** to call another php file called "**Auth.php**", which will have make a connection with a MySQL database, to search for that particular user verify the user.

The "Auth.php" will then return a json data of the user's particulars, which I intend to use in "Login.php" page, and to start a session with the **$_SESSION[]** variable of php. I also want the page to redirect the user to another page ("**Map.php**") upon successful login.

Below are parts of my codes in the "`Login.php`" and "`Auth.php`".

**Login.php**

```
<form name="myForm" action="Map.php" method="post" onsubmit="return validateForm()">
    <fieldset>
        <div class="form-group">
            <input class="form-control" placeholder="E-mail" name="email" type="email" autofocus value="<?php echo isset($_POST["email"])? $_POST["email"]: ""; ?>">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <input class="form-control" placeholder="Password" name="password" type="password" value="<?php echo isset($_POST["password"])? $_POST["password"]: ""; ?>">
        </div>
        <input type="submit" value="Login" class="btn btn-lg btn-success btn-block"/>
    </fieldset>
</form>

<script>
function validateForm() {
    //event.preventDefault();
    var email = document.forms["myForm"]["email"].value;
    var password = document.forms["myForm"]["password"].value;
    var re = /^(([^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+(\.[^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+)*)|(".+"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/;

    if (email == null || email == "") {
        alert("Email must be filled.");
        return false;
    }

    if (password == null || password == "") {
        alert("Password must be filled.");
        return false;
    }

    if(re.test(email)) {
        var data = {
            "email": email,
            "password": password
        };
        data = $(this).serialize() + "&" + $.param(data);
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            dataType: "json",
            url: "auth.php", 
            data: data,
            success: function(data) {
                alert("You have successfully logged in!");
                // TODO store user details in session
                return true; // return true to form, so will proceed to "Map.php"
            }
        });
        return false;
    }
    else {
        alert("You have entered an invalid email address!");
        return false;
    }
    return false;
}
</script>
```

**Auth.php**

```
$connection = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "bluesky");

// Test if connection succeeded
if(mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    die("Database connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error() . " (" . mysqli_connect_errno() . ") " . 
    "<br>Please retry your last action. Please retry your last action. " . 
    "<br>If problem persist, please follow strictly to the instruction manual and restart the system.");
}

$valid=true;

if (isset($_GET['email']) && isset($_GET['password'])) {
    $email = addslashes($_GET['email']);
    $password = addslashes($_GET['password']);
} else {
    $valid = false;
    $arr=array('success'=>0,'message'=>"No username or password!");
    echo json_encode($arr);
}

if($valid == true){
    $query = "SELECT * FROM user WHERE email='$email' and password='$password'";
    $result = mysqli_query($connection, $query);
    if(mysqli_num_rows($result) == 1){
        $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
        $arr=array('success'=>1,'type'=>$row['type'],'user_id'=>$row['id'],'email'=>$row['email'],'name'=>$row['name'],'phone'=>$row['phone'],'notification'=>$row['notification']);
        echo json_encode($arr);
    }else{
        $arr=array('success'=>0,'message'=>"Login failed");
        echo json_encode($arr);
    }
}

// close the connection that was established with MySQL for the SQL Query
mysqli_close($connection);
```

Comment: for validation there are several plugins.. and to use session on any page, you must have to start session by `session_start()`.

Comment: You can call "map.php" using javascript, on success return in ajax. It could be written after alert statement in success part.

Comment: @SonuBamniya yeah, I am aware of the start session, but my main problem is not knowing how to pass data from ajax to php.

Comment: Also change the type from GET to POST from your AJAX call because you are trying to send the email and password to auth.php

Comment: @AmitJha It means I do now have to use a "Post Form", so I will redirect only after verification in the javascript?

Comment: @L.Herrera Noted. Will change that.

Comment: @Jeffrey you can use alias of `$.ajax` like `$.post()` for post method and `$.get()` for get method

Comment: I think method(GET, POST) is not much related in case of forward, because in both case success will be called in case of successful login. And you have to forward in such case.

Answer (score -1):

Your ajax call should be like this:

```
data = $(this).serialize() + "&" + $.param(data)
$.post('auth.php', data, function(response){
  console.log(response);
});
```

you must use post method because you are getting password and email so its not a good practice. And for validation there is many `jQuery` plugins.

Comment: Thank you. That cut quite a number of lines of codes for me. However, how can I access the data in php? Particularly, I would like to use the code "**json_decode($json);**"

Comment: This is simply a different syntax for the ajax call and a suggestion to use `post` for security, while a good idea, neither attempts to answer the actual question